# Keep Child Objects sorted in a field_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

I have this kind of code:

```
user.posts.size #=> 5 already saved
user.posts.new(title:"foo")
user.posts.new(title:"bar")
user.posts.sort_by! { |e| e.title } #=> sort correclty
user.posts #=> sorted but with the saved on the top, the new one at the bottom
```

I use the sorting for `field_for` but obviously it's still unsorted.

Using: Rails 3.2.11 and Mongoid 3.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about why it happens that way but i think this will do the trick

```
# controller
user.posts.build(title:"foo")
user.posts.build(title:"bar")

@posts = user.posts.sort_by(&:title)

# view
= f.fields_for :posts, @posts do |post_form|
  ...
```